# Redirect Rule to match certain keywords but not others

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias

I am trying to write a `RedirectMatch` (`apache`) that matches some keywords except one.

```
...
RewriteEngine  on
RedirectMatch   ^/(banners|documents|images|static)/(.*)$ http://sb.amazonaws.com/$1/$2
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/(vrf[0-9]+)/(.*).(js|css)$  $1/$3.$4 [PT]
```

I came up with this `RedirectMatch` rule that redirects all of the urls that contain banners, documents etc. to the aws domain.

Now, I want to prevent urls that contain `temp` to go to the aws domain. For that I added `!temp`

```
RedirectMatch   ^/(!temp|banners|documents|images|static)/(.*)$ http://sb.amazonaws.com/$1/$2
```

This disallows urls like `mysite.com/temp/a.jpg` to go to AWS (but complains about an infinite loop)
but does NOT prevent `mysite.com/images/temp/a.jpg` from being redirected. What should be the correct regex for this rule?

**[EDIT]**

- mysite.com/images/foo/a.jpg should go to AWS
- mysite.com/images/foo/temp/a.jpg should NOT go to AWS
- mysite.com/temp/a.jpg should NOT got to AWS

**[EDIT2]**
This brought me close to what I was looking for

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^(images/groups/temp)/(.*)$ $1/$2 [PT]
RewriteRule ^(banners|documents|images|static)/(.*)$ http://sb.amazonaws.com/$1/$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(vrf[0-9]+)/(.*).(js|css)$  $1/$3.$4 [PT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `RedirectMatch` with `RewriteRule`. Use a `RewriteCond` to add exceptions:

```
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/groups/temp/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(banners|documents|images|static)/(.*)$ http://sb.amazonaws.com/$1/$2 [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(vrf[0-9]+)/(.*).(js|css)$  $1/$3.$4 [PT]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have added examples to clarify what I intend to achieve.

Comment: ok check updated answer now. It will allow everything inside `/images/` but won't allow `/images/groups/temp/` to be redirected to AWS.